# How to save as all output data to a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

This is a simple port scanning program. Here everything is working well. Only 2 things missing.

1. How to create and save also overwrite every output to a file.
2. Before scanning, the program should send a ping to a host to realize that host is reachable otherwise should give an error to host that is unreachable.

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

import socket
import subprocess
import sys
import argparse
 import pyfiglet     # Install if you get any error, pip install pyfiglet==0.7.5
  from datetime import datetime

   def scan_ports(host, startPort='1', endPort='1025'):
        # Clear the screen
        subprocess.call('cls', shell=True)

        ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("PORT SCANNER")
        print(ascii_banner)

        # Ask for input
        host = input("Enter a host to scan: ")
        startPort = int(input("Enter beginning port number: "))
        endPort = int(input("Enter end port number: "))

        # Check what time the scan started
        t1 = datetime.now()

        # Print a banner with information on which host we are about to scan
        print("-" * 60)
        print("Please wait, scanning ---->", host)
        print("Started at ", t1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        print("Ports range ", startPort, "to", endPort)
        print("-" * 60)
        print('\n')

        # Take the user input of 'startPort' and 'endPort' numbers and place them in a range
        # These are the port numbers to be scanned
        try:
            hostIP = socket.gethostbyname(host)
            for port in range(startPort, endPort):
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.settimeout(0.5)
                result = sock.connect_ex((hostIP, port))
                # print(result) - Can be used to test reply codes, 0=ok, 61=TCP RST, etc...
                if result == 0:
                    print("Port {}: \t Open".format(port))
                elif result == 61:
                    print("Port {}: \t Rejected by Host".format(port))
                else:
                    print("Port {}: \t Close".format(port))
                sock.close()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("You pressed Ctrl+C")
            sys.exit()

        except socket.gaierror:
            print('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
            sys.exit()

        except socket.error:
            print('Socket creation failed. Error code: ' +
                  str(err_msg[0]) + ' Error message: ' + err_msg[1])
            sys.exit()

        # Check the time once scan is complete, and compare the start - end times.
        t2 = datetime.now()
        total = t2 - t1

        # Print the scan time information
        print('\n')
        print('-' * 60)
        print('Scanning Completed in: ', total)
        print("Completed at ", t2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        print('Host IP ----> ', hostIP)
        print('-' * 60)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # Command line arguments
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Remote Port Scanner')
        parser.add_argument('--host', action="store",
                            dest="hostIP", default='localhost')
        parser.add_argument('--start-port', action="store",
                            dest="startPort", default=1, type=int)
        parser.add_argument('--end-port', action="store",
                            dest="endPort", default=100, type=int)
        # Parse arguments
        given_args = parser.parse_args()
        hostIP, startPort, endPort = given_args.hostIP, given_args.startPort, given_args.endPort
        scan_ports(hostIP, startPort, endPort)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. do you mean writing into a file? try to see about "with open" i.e:

   ```
   with open(file_name, 'w+') as the_file:
       the_file.write(test_string)
   ```
2. does in ping you mean to make an HTTP request to a known route inside a server? try using requests library in python, you will need to know what are the possible status code responses and act by them

   ```
   import requests

   x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com')
   if x.status_code == 200:
      print("ok")
   ```

Comment: once i run the program, i need to write the result to a file. which line should i put this code ?

Comment: what i meant by ping is my program algorithm should follow these steps. Basically, send ping to a host if it is up or down. If it is up then start port scanning otherwise should give an error that host is down. But my program is not checking whether host up or down, instantly start scanning ports.

Comment: you should add 1 to where in the code you are done with the result. file_name should represent the path you want to use.
you should read more about 2 and understand what it means to ping the server. your solution will be based on a logic the same as you can see here. read about HTTP request, here is a tuturial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs